# Implementing a queue between Socket.io on Node.JS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, queue

I've wrote a chat using Node.JS and Socket.io. The chat is simple: always it's a room with 2 persons, an employee and a client.

Now our volumetry is growing up and we are facing some problemas like message "disappearing" on network issues and we would like to implement a queue between our company and our clients.

Something like:

[image]

For each NodeJS proccess on picture, we have 6 VMs behind a Load Balance. I would like to know what is the best approach to work with Queues.

Should I create a topic inside the queue for each room? e.g.: for interaction between User C and D, it'll be using *messages/c:d*; for interaction between User A and B, it'll be using *messages/a:b*.

Or it's better to use a single queue without any topic, publish/subscribe all messages inside *messages* and do a broadcast for every subscriber? If the subscriber has the room, he will process that message.

In first approach, I'm not sure How should I work with MQ clients because I usually initialize them once and let it running. When I imagine to create a cache to store MQClient, where each client will be responsible for a single topic, sounds very strange in my head - If I have 10k rooms, I'll had 10k MQclients.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?